# Нижнее подчеркивание ('_') в C++

Tags: c++

Что означает использование нижнего подчеркивания в С++? Речь идет о его индивидуальном использовании, а не в составе переменной и т.п. В частности, пример:

```
template <typename T>
class VDeleter {
public:
    VDeleter() : VDeleter([](T _) {}) {}
........................................
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обычно это что-то вроде плейсхолдера. Просто переменная. В данном случае - параметр конструктора типа T.

Comment: Вы проверяли, оно компилируется? Насколько я помню имя в Си++ не может состоять только из подчеркиваний, и с цифры оно не может начинаться.

Comment: @Cerbo это было бы странным ограничением, ведь `_`, в отличие от цифр, в синтаксисе не используется. Как бы там ни было, `int main(int _, char** __) { return 0; }` спокойно собирается `g++ -Wall main.c`. `clang`у тоже норм.

Comment: @Cerbo , компилируется

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть распространённая практика, не только в C++, давать название `_` тем значениям или переменным, к которым **не будут обращаться**. Эдакое "неважно что", чему давать осмысленное имя нету (кхм) смысла.

Где-то это часть семантики языка, но в C++ это просто переменная со странным названием. Оптимизатор может догадаться выкинуть работу с этим значением, откуда возможно, пока это не влияет на *наблюдаемое поведение*. Но это никак не относится к названию, компилятор может это сделать с любой другой переменной.

То, что такое название не является "особым случаем" в семантике языка, накладывает несколько неприятных последствий:

- невозможность объявить *несколько* таких в одной области видимости (в одном списке аргументов, например)
- нестрогость соблюдения (обратиться к такой переменной технически *можно*)

Почему этот аргумент вообще там должен быть — в каждом случае надо рассматривать отдельно, но случаи бывают.

Простой пример прямо в языке: в C++ чтобы перегрузить постинкремент (`i++`), нужно перегружать `operator++(int)`. Но в оператор никакой `int` не передаётся. Зачем он? Чтобы отличить от преинкремента (`++i`), чья сигнатура `operator++()`.

Вот этот самый "бессмысленный аргумент" и можно назвать `_`. Чтобы подчеркнуть его бессмысленность.

А в случае C++ (напоминает [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry)), чаще можно **убрать название вообще**, что лишено вышеописанных недостатков.

Comment: Этот бессмысленный аргумент можно вообще не указывать и никак не именовать...

Comment: @Harry да, в С++ можно. В C `clang` ругается (но там перегрузки операторов нет вообще, это нечестное сравнение). Сейчас отмечу.

Answer (score 1):

Использование символа нижнего подчеркивания в качестве имени переменной допустимо. В данном примере переменная будет доступна в теле лямбда-функции.

Но думаю, это не самый лучший способ именования сущностей.